# Unable to import a giter project in IntellliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have created starter projects from the following link - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Tutorials

Now I want to import these projects in IntelliJ.I am trying to follow the instructions from this link but I get this error. What is the mistake? I tried importing by first selecting the complete directory and later by selecting only `build.sbt` . IntelliJ versiokn is 2016.3.4

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html#import_project

Error

```
Error while importing SBT project: ... 
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:37)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:29)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:71)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[error] Not a valid key: dump-structure (similar: buildStructure)
[error] */*:dump-structure
[error]                   ^
[INFO] [12/22/2017 05:46:39.234] [Thread-5] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
 See complete log in C:\Users\Manu\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\log\sbt.last.log  Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the latest 2016.3 version (2016.3.7)? Issue should be fixed there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11005

Comment: Same issue, 2016.3.8 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Switching to 0.13.16 worked for me (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864177/could-not-import-the-newly-generated-play-framework-project-into-intellij-idea-1)